# Filter not saved with the rest of the tab information

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I created a filtered tab and saved it: java, no android, filtered by "need answers":

[image: screenshot of tab after it is saved]

Then I clicked on the site logo, got back to the home page, clicked on my named tab - and only the tag query is restored, not the filter:

[image]

Latest stable Firefox, OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).

---

Correction: there were two errors here, now the *second* is also fixed and should go out in build `#3929` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3032` (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Have those builds been deployed already? I see no improvement at the moment.