# Back button loses filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Testing the new navigation. Starting from home page, I click [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to get to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python
and from there I click "unanswered", which points to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/?sort=unanswered which in turn redirects automatically to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?filter=need-answers&sort=votes

Now (*), if I visit a question and hit the Back button on the question page, I'm taken to a different page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes

(Reloading the page at this point makes no difference)

I'm using Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m on Win 7 32-bit.

---

Another thing that may be related:

If at (*), instead of visiting a question, I go to page 2 of results, the URL looks correct...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?filter=need-answers&sort=votes&page=2&pagesize=30

...but the questions listed there are actually from the highest-voted Python questions list, and are well answered. So, the filter seems to be ignored, even though it was not "lost" from the URL, and even though the Back button was not used at all.

If I hit Reload at this point, the URL at the browser's address bar changes to match the content that is shown:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes&page=2&pagesize=30

If I hit Reload a second time, the URL remains the same, but the content changes to page 1 of the highest voted Python question.

Comment: Use of the back button in your browser has always caused odd behaviour on Stack Exchange. You'll often get the question page in some random state you saw it a few days ago.

Comment: @TZHX Yes, but hitting the Reload button has solved that problem for me. Here, it simply reloads the wrong page again.

Comment: If I follow your instructions when I click "unanswered" it takes me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50 . To get to "sort=votes" you need to click the votes tab. How you then get the added "filter=need-answers", I don't know.

Comment: Edit your first comment into your question so it's clearer you know this isn't a cached version of the page or an issue caused by the way browsers typically treat dynamic pages.

Comment: Check to see if it's not another incarnation of [the bug I reported about losing the filter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309036/4125191).

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).